# tool fully support uml 2.0

Tags: c++, uml

I have recently used [starUML](http://staruml.sourceforge.net/en/) for my C++ projects. But I have found that it is not so powerful to support all the features of the UML 2.0. Can you recommend
any Windows based free tool to work with? I am coding on Ubuntu but sketching UML on a Windows machine.

Comment: Try [Umbrello](http://uml.sourceforge.net/download.php)

Answer (score 0):

See here and choose the one you like: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unified_Modeling_Language_tools

You can also use web-based tools, such as http://yuml.me/

Comment: you are giving list of them. I appreciate but, how can I know that which one supports full feature of uml 2.0?

Comment: I suppose any relatively recent tool from the list will support UML 2.0. starUML latest release is from 2006 which makes it very old and not much younger than UML 2.0 itself. You can scroll down the list, there is also a list of features, including the support of UML 2.0